# why this code(two pointers pointing to single variable) is showing segmentation fault during?

Tags: c, pointers

i am trying to access same variable i1 through ptr1 and ptr2 but it giving segmentation fault

```
   int i1,i2, *ptr1, *ptr2;
       i1 = 2;
       ptr1 = &i1;
       ptr1 = ptr2;
       printf("&ptr1 = %p and &ptr2 = %p\n",&ptr1,&ptr2);
       printf("value at ptr1 and ptr2 are : %d and %d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);
     i1 = 3;
       printf("value of ptr1 and ptr2 = %d,%d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);
       *ptr1 = 4;
        printf("value of ptr1 and ptr2 = %d,%d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);

       i2 = *ptr2;
        printf("value of i2 = %d\n",i2);
```

Comment: Here, `ptr1 = ptr2;` you have [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since `ptr2` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the following one: ptr2 is uninitialized and ptr1 gets the uninitialized value from it. The line

```
   ptr1 = &i1;
```

assigns the address of i1 to ptr1, but

```
   ptr1 = ptr2;
```

takes the uninitialized value from ptr2 into ptr1, so now both ptr1 and ptr2 contain uninitialized data.

Try instead doing

```
   ptr2 = ptr1;
```

i.e. ptr1 and ptr2 should switch their places.

Answer (score 0):

In your fourth line of code you are writing `ptr1 = ptr2;`whereas you have already assigned value to ptr1 while ptr2 is yet assigned. 
Basically you are assigning an unassigned pointer to ptr1. Pretty sure you will get segmentation error.Try this:

```
int i1,i2, *ptr1, *ptr2;
i1 = 2;
ptr1 = &i1;
ptr2 = ptr1;
printf("&ptr1 = %p and &ptr2 = %p\n",&ptr1,&ptr2);
printf("value at ptr1 and ptr2 are : %d and %d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);
 i1 = 3;
printf("value of ptr1 and ptr2 = %d,%d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);
 *ptr1 = 4;
printf("value of ptr1 and ptr2 = %d,%d\n",*ptr1,*ptr2);

i2 = *ptr2;
printf("value of i2 = %d\n",i2);
```

I just changed 4th line.